# Xcode missing Command Line Utility section - can't start Foundation project template

Tags: iphone, xcode

I downloaded the iPhone SDK from the iPhone dev center a couple of days ago and installed it yesterday. I'm following the Stanford iPhone development tutorials available on iTunes U. On Assignment 1B, the first instruction is to open a new Foundation Project template. The screenshot shows several sections in Xcode which my version doesn't seem to have, including the Command Line Utility section which the Foundation Project template is shown to be in.

Does this need to be installed manually? I tried searching on Google with no luck. The fact that I'm an OS X newbie doesn't really help any either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you running on Snow Leopard (10.6)? I would assume the Stanford class is Leopard (10.5). These have different versions of Xcode. The new layout is actually a bit nicer, but you'll have to poke around a bit to find the equivalents of the old templates. In many cases, they've merged things that used to be separate templates into a single template with options. They one you're probably looking for is now in  "Mac OS X>Application>Command Line Tool" and then you select "Foundation" as the type.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I am  using 10.6. I'll try using the Command Line Tool to complete the assignment, hopefully it's the equivalent. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> It works! After selecting Command Line Tool, you can find the "Foundation" type that Rob mentioned in a little drop down menu near the middle of the window

To add on, the Type selection is in the same page as selecting Command Line Tool, the default type is : C